# Apple "Deferred Lighting" is all green on my MacBook Pro 2018 with Vega 20

Tags: swift, metal, deferred, lighting

I downloaded the example [Deferred Lighting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/deferred_lighting) provided by Apple in its documentation. Xcode compiles it with no errors but the colors are basically all green (see [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8TNG.jpg)). It could be due to my graphics card but I don't know how to fix the code accordingly. I tried to change pixel formats but none seems to be a fix. I have also noticed that the Albedo + Shadow GBuffer is saturated (see [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvLrD.jpg)) and might be the cause. The sky box looks as it should, instead.

MacBook: Pro (15-inch, 2018) with 2,9 GHz Intel Core i9

Memory 32 GB 2400 MHz DDR4

Graphics: Radeon Pro Vega 20 4 GB and Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot.

Comment: I have jus added it.